# Pandas.Dataframe: Is there an efficient way to translate multiple WHERE SQL statements?

Tags: python, sql, pandas

So I want to translate something like

```
SELECT *
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE MY_ATTRIBUTE IN (8945, 8899, 4501, 6874, 3256, 8881, 1017)
```

in python using Pandas dataframe.

Reading [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/comparison_with_sql.html), the way to do so is

```
mydataframe[mydataframe['myattribute'] == 8945 | 
            mydataframe['myattribute'] == 8899 | 
            mydataframe['myattribute'] == 4501 | 
            mydataframe['myattribute'] == 6874 | 
            mydataframe['myattribute'] == 3256 | 
            mydataframe['myattribute'] == 8881 | 
            mydataframe['myattribute'] == 1017]
```

This is quite unaesthetic and becomes worse with long attributes and a large value list.

Is there a way to do it properly with less redundant code?

Something like

```
mydataframe[mydataframe['myattribute'] in (8945, 8899, 4501, 6874, 3256, 8881, 1017)]
```

would be nice, but it raises the following error:

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Series` method `isin()` to compare with list:

```
mydataframe[mydataframe['myattribute'].isin([8945, 8899, 4501, 6874, 3256, 8881, 1017])]
```